# How to change the border size of a single window?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible to change the border width for a single window? I know you can change the border width for all windows, but I want to change only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do it by owner-drawn your only options are changing the border type between dialog, fixed single and none. They are of different thicknesses and looks and behaviors so not a great choice. Making your own is definitely the only way to go.

AN easy way to "create your own border" coould actually be to do [Windows Skinning](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Win32_Window_Skinning.shtml)

Comment: Hm, I need the window to have the same look and feel as the others. It needs to be resizable and with glass border and shadow on Win7. Unfortunately window skinning would make the window "different", which I'd like to avoid. It would also lead to other problems with theming I think.